# What does it mean to say "Java Modified UTF-8 Encoding"?

Tags: java

What does it mean to say "Java Modified UTF-8 Encoding" ? How is it different from normal UTF-8 Encoding?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8

Comment: Java, always wanting to do everything its way.

Comment: @BoltClock Not a very constructive comment. It looks like Java uses this modified encoding only in cases where the String might end up in an environment that uses 0x00 terminated Strings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is described in detail in the javadoc of [`DataInput`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8):

> #### [Modified UTF-8](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8)
>
> Implementations of the `DataInput` and `DataOutput` interfaces represent Unicode strings in a format that is a slight modification of UTF-8. (For information regarding the standard UTF-8 format, see section *3.9 Unicode Encoding Forms of The Unicode Standard, Version 4.0*). Note that in the following tables, the most significant bit appears in the far left-hand column.
>
> *... (some tables, please click the javadoc link to see yourself) ...*
>
> The differences between this format and the standard UTF-8 format are the following:
>
> - The null byte `'\u0000'` is encoded in 2-byte format rather than 1-byte, so that the encoded strings never have embedded nulls.
> - Only the 1-byte, 2-byte, and 3-byte formats are used.
> - [Supplementary characters](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) are represented in the form of surrogate pairs.

How to read it is described in detail in the javadoc of [`DataInput#readUTF()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29):

> #### [readUTF](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29)
>
> ```
> String readUTF()
>            throws IOException
> ```
>
> Reads in a string that has been encoded using a [modified UTF-8](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8) format. The general contract of `readUTF` is that it reads a representation of a Unicode character string encoded in modified UTF-8 format; this string of characters is then returned as a `String`.
>
> First, two bytes are read and used to construct an unsigned 16-bit integer in exactly the manner of the `readUnsignedShort` method . This integer value is called the *UTF length* and specifies the number of additional bytes to be read. These bytes are then converted to characters by considering them in groups. The length of each group is computed from the value of the first byte of the group. The byte following a group, if any, is the first byte of the next group.
>
> If the first byte of a group matches the bit pattern `0xxxxxxx` (where `x` means "may be `0` or `1`"), then the group consists of just that byte. The byte is zero-extended to form a character.
>
> If the first byte of a group matches the bit pattern `110xxxxx`, then the group consists of that byte `a` and a second byte `b`. If there is no byte `b` (because byte `a` was the last of the bytes to be read), or if byte `b` does not match the bit pattern `10xxxxxx`, then a `UTFDataFormatException` is thrown. Otherwise, the group is converted to the character:
>
> ```
> (char)(((a& 0x1F) << 6) | (b & 0x3F))
> ```
>
> If the first byte of a group matches the bit pattern `1110xxxx`, then the group consists of that byte `a` and two more bytes `b` and `c`. If there is no byte `c` (because byte `a` was one of the last two of the bytes to be read), or either byte `b` or byte `c` does not match the bit pattern `10xxxxxx`, then a `UTFDataFormatException` is thrown. Otherwise, the group is converted to the character:
>
> ```
> (char)(((a & 0x0F) << 12) | ((b & 0x3F) << 6) | (c & 0x3F))
> ```
>
> If the first byte of a group matches the pattern `1111xxxx` or the pattern `10xxxxxx`, then a `UTFDataFormatException` is thrown.
>
> If end of file is encountered at any time during this entire process, then an `EOFException` is thrown.
>
> After every group has been converted to a character by this process, the characters are gathered, in the same order in which their corresponding groups were read from the input stream, to form a `String`, which is returned.
>
> The `writeUTF` method of interface `DataOutput` may be used to write data that is suitable for reading by this method.

Comment: *"The null byte is encoded in 2-byte format"* — Does that mean that it is encoded as `11000000 10000000`?

Comment: @MCEmperor Yes.

Answer (score 3):

The Java programming language, which uses UTF-16 for its internal text representation, supports a non-standard modification of UTF-8 for string serialization. This encoding is called modified UTF-8. There are two differences between modified and standard UTF-8. The first difference is that the null character (U+0000) is encoded with two bytes instead of one, specifically as 11000000 10000000.

Comment: You might want to mention the second difference.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8

> "In normal usage, the Java programming language supports standard
>   UTF-8 when reading and writing strings through InputStreamReader and
>   OutputStreamWriter. However it uses Modified UTF-8 for object
>   serialization, for the Java Native Interface, and for
>   embedding constant strings in class files."