# How to convert the "Java modified UTF-8" to the regular UTF-8 and back?

Tags: java, c, utf-8, jniwrapper

I have created a Java wrapper around a native C library and have a question about the string encodings. There are slight differences in the “Java modified UTF-8” encoding that is used by Java from the regular UTF-8. And these differences may cause serious problems: the JNI functions may crash the app when passed the regular UTF-8 because it may contain byte sequences forbidden for the “Java modified UTF-8”. Please see the following topic: [What does it mean to say "Java Modified UTF-8 Encoding"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921016/what-does-it-mean-to-say-java-modified-utf-8-encoding)

My question is what is a standard reliable way to convert the “Java modified UTF-8” to the regular UTF-8 and back?

Comment: if you can get the bytes, there's an answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655891/converting-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-in-java-how-to-keep-it-as-single-byte?rq=1

Comment: Don't use `DataInput`, it is not intended for cross-language data exchange. Your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454), i.e. you've decided to use `DataInput` for reading a string from a C library, and that is not the right choice. Go back a step, describe your real problem, i.e. what is the format of the string data coming from C, then ask: How do I read that in Java?

Comment: ICU can do it, but it'll have to pass through UTF-16 in the middle. [Documentation](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html#aef59ec61e141905bf7b5970ae21f5dd2).

Comment: Note that although Java's modified UTF-8 is *almost* identical to UTF-8 for characters assigned to Unicode's basic multilingual plane, it is quite different for other characters.  The differences can be expressed very simply, but the actual encoded data for non-BMP characters is completely different between the two.

Comment: Essentially any solution has to pass through UTF-16 (at least in some sense) internally since the "Java-modified" thing is just encoding UTF-16 code units in a UTF-8-like encoding (plus misencoding NUL).

Answer (score 4):

> My question is what is a standard reliable way to convert the “Java
>   modified UTF-8” to the regular UTF-8 and back?

First, consider whether you really need or want to do that.  The only reason I can think of for doing so in the context of wrapping a C library is to use the JNI functions that work with Java `String`s in terms of byte arrays encoded in modified UTF-8, but that's neither the only nor the best way to proceed except in rather specific circumstances.

For most cases, I would recommend going directly from UTF-8 to String objects, and getting Java to do most of that work.  Simple tools Java provides for that include the constructor `String(byte[], String)`, which initializes a String with data whose encoding you specify, and `String.getBytes(String)`, which gives you the string's character data in the encoding of your choice.  Both of these are limited to encodings known to the JVM, but UTF-8 is guaranteed to be among those.  You can use those directly from your JNI code, or provide suitable for-purpose wrapper methods for your JNI code to invoke.

If you really do want the modified UTF-8 form for its own sake, then your JNI code can obtain it from the corresponding Java string (obtained as summarized above) via the `GetStringUTFChars` JNI function, and you can go the other way with `NewStringUTF`.  Of course, this makes Java `String`s the intermediate form, which is entirely appropos in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for your replies! I finally found the answer.
The only documented way of such conversions is using InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter

> In normal usage, the Java programming language supports standard UTF-8
>   when reading and writing strings through InputStreamReader and
>   OutputStreamWriter (if it is the platform's default character set or
>   as requested by the program).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8

Also the NewStringUTF JNI method expects the Modified UTF-8 input, not the standard one. And it will crash the app if it receives a forbidden byte sequence and the JNI Exception handling can't prevent it from crashing the app.

So my second conclusion is that passing String/jstring from JNI to Java or the other way is always a bad idea. Never do that. Perform all of the conversions with the InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter on the Java layer and pass the raw byte arrays to/from the JNI.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing that can only be achieved by using some library. You can always do it yourself.

<sup>Note: class `Buffer` below just wraps an array of `byte` the same way a `String` wraps an array of `char`.</sup>

```
public static String stringFromBuffer( Buffer buffer )
{
    String result = stringFromBuffer0( buffer );
    assert bufferFromString0( result ).equals( buffer );
    return result;
}

public static Buffer bufferFromString( String s )
{
    Buffer result = bufferFromString0( s );
    assert stringFromBuffer( result ).equals( s );
    return result;
}

private static String stringFromBuffer0( Buffer buffer )
{
    byte[] bytes = buffer.getBytes();
    int end = bytes.length;
    char[] chars = new char[end];
    int t = 0;
    for( int s = 0; s < end; )
    {
        int b1 = bytes[s++] & 0xff;
        assert b1 >> 4 >= 0;
        if( /*b1 >> 4 >= 0 &&*/ b1 >> 4 <= 7 ) /* 0x0xxx_xxxx */
            chars[t++] = (char)b1;
        else if( b1 >> 4 >= 8 && b1 >> 4 <= 11 ) /* 0x10xx_xxxx */
            throw new MalformedUtf8Exception( s - 1 );
        else if( b1 >> 4 >= 12 && b1 >> 4 <= 13 ) /* 0x110x_xxxx 0x10xx_xxxx */
        {
            assert s < end : new IncompleteUtf8Exception( s - 1 );
            int b2 = bytes[s++] & 0xff;
            assert (b2 & 0xc0) == 0x80 : new MalformedUtf8Exception( s - 1 );
            chars[t++] = (char)(((b1 & 0x1f) << 6) | (b2 & 0x3f));
        }
        else if( b1 >> 4 == 14 ) /* 0x1110_xxxx 0x10xx_xxxx 0x10xx_xxxx */
        {
            assert s < end : new IncompleteUtf8Exception( s - 1 );
            int b2 = bytes[s++] & 0xff;
            assert (b2 & 0xc0) == 0x80 : new MalformedUtf8Exception( s - 1 );
            assert s < end : new IncompleteUtf8Exception( s - 1 );
            int b3 = bytes[s++] & 0xff;
            assert (b3 & 0xc0) == 0x80 : new MalformedUtf8Exception( s - 1 );
            chars[t++] = (char)(((b1 & 0x0f) << 12) | ((b2 & 0x3f) << 6) | (b3 & 0x3f));
        }
        else /* 0x1111_xxxx */
            throw new MalformedUtf8Exception( s - 1 );
    }
    return new String( chars, 0, t );
}

private static Buffer bufferFromString0( String s )
{
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[chars.length * 3];
    int p = 0;
    for( char c : chars )
    {
        if( (c >= 1) && (c <= 0x7f) )
            bytes[p++] = (byte)c;
        else if( c > 0x07ff )
        {
            bytes[p++] = (byte)(0xe0 | ((c >> 12) & 0x0f));
            bytes[p++] = (byte)(0x80 | ((c >> 6) & 0x3f));
            bytes[p++] = (byte)(0x80 | (c & 0x3f));
        }
        else
        {
            bytes[p++] = (byte)(0xc0 | ((c >> 6) & 0x1f));
            bytes[p++] = (byte)(0x80 | (c & 0x3f));
        }
    }
    if( p > 0xffff )
        throw new StringTooLongException( p );
    return Buffer.create( bytes, 0, p );
}
```