# How to use env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(...) after env->GetStringUTFChars(...)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am learning to use C++ in Android.

The following function works well, but I do not know how to use `ReleaseStringUTFChars(fileName, 0)` to release (or free) the memory allocated by `env->GetStringUTFChars(input, 0);`

```
Activity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject, /* this */
        jstring input) {
    const char *str_C = env->GetStringUTFChars(input, 0);
    char *data = funcX(str_C); // funcX allocates with malloc

    // env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(input, str_C); ???

    free(data); // Freeing funcX allocations
    return env->NewStringUTF(someString.c_str());
}
```

Also, I have been trying to see the documentation, but I can't find it.
How can I check if the memory is being released or freed correctly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Per the [JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) (which is available on Oracle's website, the owner of Java), you simply need to pass to `ReleaseStringUTFChars()` the original `jstring` and the `const char *` pointer that `GetStringUTFChars()` returned, eg:

```cpp
Activity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject, /* this */
        jstring input)
{
    const char *str_C = env->GetStringUTFChars(input, 0);
    char *data = funcX(str_C); // funcX allocates with malloc
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(input, str_C);

    // ... data is being used ...
    // ... data is being used ...

    free(data); // Freeing funcX allocations
    return env->NewStringUTF(someString.c_str());
}
```

---

On a side note, note that JNI deals with [**Modified** UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921016/), not *standard* UTF-8.  But most C++ code that deals with UTF-8 is likely to deal with *standard* UTF-8, not **Modified** UTF-8.  So, it is generally better to deal with Java strings in their native UTF-16 encoding rather than UTF-8, if you can help it (`GetStringChars()`, `ReleaseStringChars()`, `NewString()`, etc).