# Convert c++ string with cyrillic letters to jstring

Tags: c++, string, java-native-interface, cyrillic

I am trying to convert a c++ string with cyrillic russian letters to JNI jstring
But i getting different string in the output

My code that converts string to jstring:

```
const char* msg = "привет";
return env->NewStringUTF(msg);
```

Output in java:

```
ïðèâåò
```

How to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to make sure your input `char*` string is encoded in UTF-8 to begin with (which it isn't, in your example).

Second, JNI's `NewStringUTF()` method requires the input string to be encoded in [**modified** UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921016/), not in *standard* UTF-8.

When dealing with non-ASCII chracters, you are better off using a UTF-16 encoded `char16_t*`/`wchar_t*` string with JNI's `NewString()` method instead.